# List multiple directories contents and its path

Tags: linux, bash

I want to write a linux script or command that will:

Look into multiple specific directories and list its contents

For example

```
/test/dir1/abc/version1/program_name/

/test/dir1/abc/version2/program_name/

/test/dir1/abc/version3/program_name/

/test/dir1/bca/version1/program_name/

/test/dir1/bca/version2/program_name/

/test/dir1/bca/version3/program_name/

/test/dir1/cab/version1/program_name/

/test/dir1/cab/version2/program_name/

/test/dir1/cab/version3/program_name/
```

I can do a

```
ls -al /test/dir1/*/
```

and see its contents. But I just want to see what it inside version2 and version3.

for example

```
ls -al /test/dir1/*/<version2 or version3>/*
```

and get a list like:

```
/test/dir1/abc/version2/program_name/

/test/dir1/abc/version3/program_name/

/test/dir1/bca/version2/program_name/

/test/dir1/bca/version3/program_name/

/test/dir1/cab/version2/program_name/

/test/dir1/cab/version3/program_name/
```

Not including version1. There is more directories than version1, version2, and version3. Thats why just excluding version1 doesnt work.

Any help really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use two glob expansions for this search. Try this:

```
ls -al /test/dir1/*/version[23]/*
```

It will search through all of the /test/dir1/* directories, and then look for subdirectories matching either 'version2' or 'version3'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list` feature (glob) in BASH:

```
ls -al /test/dir1/*/{version2,version3}/*
```

Comment: Thanks, it works (Didnt knew about list (glob). Any way I can modify the output on the fly? That command return something like: 
/test/dir1/abc/version2/program_name/: 
/test/dir1/abc/version3/program_name/:
/test/dir1/bca/version2/program_name/: 

Any way to remove that colon, so I can get the full path only?

Comment: If you want to parse/alter the output then better to use BASH array i.e. `arr=( /test/dir1/*/{version2,version3}/* )` and then take it forward.